# NetworkManager is APSupported

Tags: java, codenameone, networkmanager

I want to consume a service. I am 100% sure that this service works correctly.

**Service call**

```
public void add(User user) {
ConnectionRequest con = new ConnectionRequest();

String url="http://localhost/NY/untitled/web/app_dev.php/user/new"
+ "?Fonctionuser="+user.getUserFunction()
+"&Fullname="+user.getUserName()
+"&Imageproduit="+user.getUserImage()
+"&Latitude="+user.getLatitude()
+"&Longitude="+user.getLongitude()
+"&State="+user.getUserState();
System.out.println(user.getUserState());

con.setUrl(url);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con); 
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.isAPSupported(NetworkManager.java:866)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.<init>(ConnectionRequest.java:330)
at Services.UserServices.add(UserServices.java:18)
at Services.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
  User user = new User(); 
  user.setLatitude(111); 
  user.setLongitude(111); 
  user.setUserFunction( UserFunction.Client.ordinal()); 
  user.setUserImage("uezfniez"); 
  user.setUserState((int)UserState.Hold.ordinal()); 
  user.setUserName("jamel"); 
  UserServices userServices = new UserServices(); 
  userServices.add(user); 
}
```

Comment: Can you pleae post the classes names? and maybe some line numbers too. Is this code in the main methd?

Comment: Thanks for reply ,
No its My service Function

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)  {
       User user = new User();
       user.setLatitude(111);
       user.setLongitude(111);
       user.setUserFunction( UserFunction.Client.ordinal());
       user.setUserImage("uezfniez");
       user.setUserState((int)UserState.Hold.ordinal());
       user.setUserName("jamel");
       UserServices userServices = new UserServices();
       userServices.add(user);
   }

Answer (score 0):

It seems you nedd to write your code in an Action Listener

```
registerButton.addActionListener(e -> {
        con.setUrl("http://localhost/NY/untitled/web/app_dev.php/user/"
                + "new?Fonctionuser=2&Fullname=jamel&Imageproduit=uezfniez&Latitude=111&Longitude=111&State=2");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(con);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you invoked that code from the constructor or a static initializer which means the implementation of Codename One didn't finish initializing. No code that relies on implementation should be executed before the `init(Object)` method is invoked.

Action listeners happen well after that point and would thus work well in this case.